# How to setup rvm installed ruby as system default ruby version in ubuntu

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ubuntu, rvm, ruby-on-rails-2

I have **ruby 2.0.0p247 (2013-06-27 revision 41674) [x86_64-linux]** installed on an ubuntu system. I also have rvm installed which has ruby version **ruby 1.8.7 (2013-06-27 patchlevel 374) [x86_64-linux]**. I am using rvm installed ruby version to run my project. **Can I make the rvm installed ruby as my default ruby environment?** I used the command

```
rvm --default use 1.8.7
```

This command only made the rvm installed ruby version as default for the current login session. Once I logged out and logged in again the system shows the default system ruby version. Please help.

Comment: Once you use `rvm` for ruby managing, you simply do not need the system-wide version. Feel free to `apt-get remove`.

Comment: @mudasobwa: Thank you for answering but the below mentioned script solved my problem.

Comment: `rvm` forces you to start a terminal as login shell (as far as I remember). Writing a script seems like an overkill to me. There must something in the configuration that you missed out (maybe?).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the way to sort this problem if it helps anyone. I made a script test.sh as follows -

```
# Load RVM into a shell session *as a function*
if [[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] ; then

    # First try to load from a user install
    source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"

elif [[ -s "/usr/local/rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] ; then

    # Then try to load from a root install
    source "/usr/local/rvm/scripts/rvm"

else

    printf "ERROR: An RVM installation was not found.\n"

fi

rvm use 1.8.7
```

On running this script it will try to load rvm and then automatically switch to rvm installed ruby version.

Answer (score 1):

Use `.rvmrc` only incase you have to use complex initial scripting, otherwise use filepair `.ruby-version`, `.ruby-gemset`, so

```
$ cd your_project
$ echo "1.8.7" > .ruby-version
$ echo "your_project" > .ruby-gemset
$ cd ..
$ cd your_project
$ bunde install
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope you have set RVM environment settings to .bashrc or your .bash_profile file.

```
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin # Add RVM to PATH for scripting
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && . "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM function
```

You can remove built-in Ruby version installed on Ubuntu by `sudo apt-get purge ruby`.

if Ruby version specify you can try this `sudo apt-get purge ruby1.9` or ruby2.x

Comment: Thank you but I found out another way which I can use with a cron job as well to execute rake tasks associated with a particular ruby gemset.